# How to make a string compare non case sensitive?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a code for one of those programs that responds according to your answers. I want to make it so that some of the variables are not case sensitive. For example if my variable `x` is equal to `"Me"` I want it to also equal `"me"`. Is that possible?

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Tutorial {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        System.out.println("Who goes there?");
        Scanner N = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = N.next();
        if (name.equals("me") || name.equals("Me")){
                System.out.println("Well, good for you smartass.");
                System.exit(1);
        }else System.out.printf("Nice to meet you, %s.%n", name);   
        System.out.print("How are you doing?");
        Scanner d1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String doing = d1.next();
        switch(doing){
        case "good": System.out.println("that is nice to hear.");
        case "Well": System.out.println("that is nice to hear.");
        case "bad" : System.out.println("That's ruff mate.");
        case "Awesome" : System.out.println("Nice");
        case "Terrible" : System.out.println("Sucks for you");

        }
    }
}
```

I don't want to have to make 2 cases for each answer where one is uppercase and the other is lower case.

Slightly off topic question. How do I close the resource leaks for the scanner?

Comment: `N.close` for the resource leak; use [case-insensitive compares](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) for the Me/me/mE

Comment: Question title is misleading. Rename, please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Worth mentioning [`String#toLowerCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29):

```
name.toLowerCase().equals("me");
```

Or simply use [`String#equalsIgnoreCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29):

```
name.equalsIgnoreCase("me");
```

Comment: or `"me".equalsIgnoreCase(name)` to avoid the NPE ;)

Comment: @RC. I hate this approach :/ It might hide serious logic problems and possible bugs..

Comment: @RC. That's right.. but imagine a case where `null` was inserted instead of actual String due to some bug.. using `"string".equals(someString)` won't throw an *exception*.. and you will never know `someString` is bad..

Comment: Or, imagine a case where null is a valid value and you don't WANT an exception to be thrown.

Comment: @DavidWallace If `null` is valid I prefer to treat separately.

Comment: as I said matter of taste, kind of "defensive vs offensive" programming

Comment: If null is NOT valid, I prefer to check this, and throw the necessary exception (or take whatever other action is appropriate) in its own piece of logic.  Not to piggyback my validation into some other piece of logic.  Sorry, Maroun, but I firmly believe that RC's way is superior.

Comment: @DavidWallace Once it happened to me.. due to server failure, my array wasn't filled with all Strings, and got `null` values in it. `"string".equals(string);` hided the un-welcomed `null` value and I didn't know about the bug.. only in advanced stage..

Comment: So if it was important not to have nulls, you should have validated it separately, and taken the appropriate action in its own piece of code.

Comment: @Maroun Maroun How exactly would I use it for the doing variable. What am I supposed to put in the parameter of doing.equalsIgnoreCase(); I tried to put in doing but it did not work

Comment: @DarkAriel7 I don't understand what you mean, can you please elaborate more on that?

Comment: @Maroun Maroun I want to set my variable "doing" to ignore cases to try it out in my Switch/case. What do I have to put in the parenthesis part of doing.equals.IgnoreCase()? I tried putting in the parenthesis but when I do so nothing happens and the program just stalls there.

Comment: Then lower-case the String before the `swtich` and then `switch` on "mylowercasedstring".

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to do no case sensitive variable. From your code you want to threat answers in strings into a switch and do some action that depends on answer.

I think the best way is to take user input a use on that string [upper method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_touppercase.htm) from string class.

```
YourString =  YourString.toUpperCase();
```